# How to load data in layout which will be there in extended version also?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my recent project on Laravel. I have extended some views from layouts folder.

I have a `dashboard.blade.php` file inside of layouts folder which has data from database. Now if i tried to extend the dashboard in another view should i write the same Query in that another view?

**Scenario:**

If I show list of courses in dashboard view, and extend the view suppose course details page where also should have list of courses. should i write Query for that view also?